# Jest testcase failed due to unexpected token while parsing a flow type in react-native

Tags: jestjs, flowtype

I am trying to setup jest with my react-native app. I created a simple test case and while running `npm test`, I get the following error

```
 FAIL  __tests__/actionsSpecs.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /Users/abc/Projects/MyApp/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/src/renderers/shared/hooks/ReactHostOperationHistoryHook.js: Unexpected token (20:4)
        18 |   & {instanceID: DebugID}
        19 |   & (
      > 20 |     | {type: 'mount', payload: string}
           |     ^
        21 |     | {type: 'insert child', payload: {toIndex: number, content: string}}
        22 |     | {type: 'move child', payload: {fromIndex: number, toIndex: number}}
        23 |     | {type: 'replace children', payload: string}
```

Basically, it is failing on a flow type declaration. I have tried using `flow` babel preset and `transform-flow-strip-types` but that didn't help.

Below is my jest configuration in package.json

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "setupFiles": [
      "./setup.js"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [ "node_modules/(?!react-native)" ]
  }
```

This is the `.babelrc` file

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native", "flow"]
}
```

It looks like the `flow` preset didn't get rid of the flow types during transpilation but I don't know how to get it to work now.

Please let me know if you know what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need more than just presets, you also need a transform that strips flowtypes. Usually this is done with with the babel plugin [babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types).

Your `.babelrc` file should look something like this:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react-native"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-flow-strip-types"
  ]
}
```

Edit: Another possibility is that your flow syntax is incorrect, and the transform doesn't know how to handle it. It looks to me from the snippet you've pasted that there's an extra `|` preceding the object definition on line 20. Does removing that change the output at all?

Comment: I have tried using both the `flow` preset and `transform-flow-strip-types` but I get the same error as described above in both the cases. I guess the problem is that `babel` is not kicking in because either of those should fix it.

Comment: Can you share the `jest` part of your package.json?

Comment: I already have it in the question. The `transformIgnorePatterns` was something that I got from various questions and issues around similar topics. I have tried it with and without the `transformIgnorePatterns` but it didn't help.

Comment: Oh sorry, you're right! I missed that. I asked because if you have `"transform": {}` in your jest config, it will ignore all transforms. I've updated my answer above with another possibility.

Comment: The code where this error is reported is `react-native` code and the flow declaration is correct as per documentation. I was previously using node v5.9.1 and I updated to node v8.2.1 and reinstalled all the node_modules and that seemed to have fixed the error. Not sure how does node version affect the flow declarations.